# convert android xml drawable to sgv (reverse android studio function)

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I want do somthing reverse of android studio xml drawable converting and get SVG file from XML Drawable but I didn't find any online or software solution to do this

Comment: use apktool https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: apk tool used for ubfuscate classes not xml drawable to vector !